# How to eliminate extra cr lf in outputfile

Tags: powershell

I have a collection of strings (bunch of HTML elements) all ending with a carriage return(cr) and a linefeed(lf).
Each line in the collection looks like

```
<div>Some text</div>crlf
```

When I send this collection to a file I have an extra crlf between each line. Both of these produce an extra crlf in the text file

```
$lines > tmp.txt
$lines -join "`r`n" > tmp.txt
```

The file looks like

```
<div>Some text</div>crlf
crlf
<div>Some more text</div>crlf
crlf
```

If I use -join ""  I end up with no line breaks at all.

How do I get just one line bread per array member?

Answer (score 1):

Either of these should work

```
$lines |%{$_.TrimEnd()} > tmp.txt
$lines -replace '\r\n$', '' > tmp.txt
```

Comment: sorry, both produce an extra CRLF.  the -replace doesn't seem to do anything.  If I use '\n', 'xxx'.  out put doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

Comments can't format the escape character so I'll answer it here.
This works:

```
$lines -join "`r`n" -replace "`r`n`r`n", "`r`n" > tmp.txt
```